# stored long description in Sqlite database manager in iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I want to store long description in sqlite database manager in iphone like this data.

"The Golden Temple: The Golden Temple, popular as Sri Harmandir Sahib or Sri Darbar Sahib, is the sacred seat of Sikhism. Bathed in a quintessential golden hue that dazzles in the serene waters of the Amrit Sarovar that lace around it, the swarn mandir (Golden temple) is one that internalizes in the mindscape of its visitors, no matter what religion or creed, as one of the most magnificent House of Worship. On a jewel-studded platform is the Adi Grantha or the sacred scripture of Sikhs wherein are enshrined holy inscriptions by the ten Sikh gurus and various Hindu and Moslem saints. While visiting the Golden Temple you need to cover your head. Street sellers sell bandanas outside the temple at cheap prices."

I am trying to take as description (VARCHAR(5000)) but when i execute query it is showing half text with dotted (....) like that  https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyMqi.png

Thanks

Comment: Urgent for you perhaps, but not for anyone else using this site. Please don't write 'urgent' in questions. If it's really urgent, feel free to hire someone to help.

Comment: If i can hire anyone then i didnot ask any question here OKKK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `...` surely indicate that the full text is present in the database. It also indicates that "Sqlite database browser" [truncates past a certain length](http://sqlitebrowser.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sqlitebrowser/trunk/src/preferences.cpp?revision=69&view=markup):

```
m_textWidthMarkSize = s.value("prefs/sqleditor/textWidthMarkSpinBox", 60).toInt();
```

Is there a way to change the settings?

**Edit**

You can verify that the text is fully saved with the following query (replace `theTable` with the correct table name):

```
select length(description) from theTable;
```

Comment: Yes, I think you are right but can you tell me how can i solve this problem.

Comment: I am creating table in sqlite database manager for iphone. So in able i have Description column for type (VARCHAR (5000)) in description column i need to store long text but it is not storing long text. So i donot know where is change the settings. can you know something about it.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, the text is most probably fully stored, it's the retrieval that cuts after X characters. I'll edit my answer with a way of verifying that all the text is indeed in the database.